# Unique & Linkable Document ID Across SharePoint Farm

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, document-id

We have a requirement to link directly to documents across the SharePoint Farm. Currently links are based on document name & document ids are only unique within the site collection.

We have multiple content databases / site collections in the Farm.

How can users send links directly to documents that will always be uniquely identifiable across the whole Farm?

Comment: So no way to do this?

Comment: Funny, I've looked for something different but came up to this article: http://nikcharlebois.com/unique-document-id-across-the-farm-with-custom-document-id-provider/
At least the farmwide unique DocID is handled there, didn't read the entire post, though.